# Solving Laplace equation with discontinuous boundary conditions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

**What I need**

I am trying to implement a C++ code that solves Laplace's equation in the following situation:

I have a set of $N$ cylindrical shells one after the other. Each cylindrical shell has a different radius and length. The spacing between cylinders is also different for each pair. My configuration looks similar to the image above, each cylinder is held at a fixed potential, and it is empty (unlike the image); my system is just a bunch of cylinder surfaces.

I need to solve $\nabla ^2 \phi = 0$ with boundary conditions:

$$\phi(R_i, z_i) = \phi_i $$ for $i= 1, 2,...,N$, where $R_i$ is the radius of he $i^{th}$ cylinder, and it extends along $z_i$ from $a_i$ to $b_i$.

[image]

**What I have tried**

Given the azimuthal symmetry in my configuration then Laplace equation is:
$$\frac{\partial ^2 \phi}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial ^2 \phi}{\partial z^2} = 0$$

And after separation of variables the problem reduces to:
$$\frac{d^2Z}{dz^2} - k^2Z = 0$$
$$\frac{d^2R}{dr^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{dR}{dr} + k^2R = 0$$
where $k$ is just a constant.

The solutions would then be of the form:
$$Z(z) = A\exp(kz)+B\exp(-kz)$$
$$R(r) = J_0(kr)$$

Where $J_0$ is a Bessel function of first kind.

**What I am struggling with**

As $\phi$ vanishes when $z$ tends to infinity and minus infinity, wouldn't these conditions set both $A$ and $B$ in $Z(z)$ to zero?

I am also very confused as to how the value of $k$ is dealt with. Is the solution $Z \times R$ summed over values of $k$? How do the set of boundary conditions come into place, would they restrict $k$?

I was trying to take advantage of the in-built Bessel functions in C++ and was hoping to get the solutions using that, but I am just getting confused with this problem.

Comment: Why do you think $\phi$ should vanish for $z$ going to plus or minus infinity? You are only looking for a solution in some compact domain $z \in [a_i, b_i]$

Comment: The boundary condition $\phi$ vanishing at infinity is due to the physical nature of $\phi$. What other boundary condition could I set at $a_i, b_i$? All I know is that the potential vanishes at infinity.

Comment: Setting the solution to zero at $a_i$ and $b_i$ already gives you a nontrivial solution. With a boundary condition at each end you have a unique solution and the unique solution for the entire real line vanishing at both ends happens to be the zero solution.

Comment: Related Phys.SE post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/509932/2451

Comment: Separability of solutions is an assumption / simplification one can make in order to try to make a problem more tractable; it's not something that always works. If it leads to something nonsensical, then... it's just not separable :/

Comment: Just my curiosity: are you designing a focusing/defocusing system for a beam made of charged particles?